Unable to open a modal from within my teams application
I am create a teams application and is built using angular using the MDBootstrap packages. The application itself is hosted using AWS cloudfront.
Now the issue I am having is when I open a modal from within the application in teams I get the following error in the console:
Blocked a frame with origin "https://prod.code.myurl.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://teams.microsoft.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
Note when the modal is opened I am not even calling any external api or anything.
This is how I am opening the modal:
  public openModal(formFileName: any) {
    const config = {
      modalClass: 'modal-xl',
      ignoreBackdropClick: true,
      animation: false,
      data: {
        title: 'FormLoader'
      },
    }
    let modalRef = this.modalService.open(FormLoaderModalComponent, config);
    modalRef.onClose.subscribe(async (message: any) => {
      console.log('Modal closed');
    });
  }
}

and this is the FormLoaderModalComponent:
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MdbModalRef} from "mdb-angular-ui-kit/modal";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-loader-modal',
  templateUrl: './form-loader-modal.component.html',
  styleUrl: './form-loader-modal.component.scss'
})
export class FormLoaderModalComponent {
  title: string | null = null;
  formFileName: string | null = null;

  constructor(public modalRef: MdbModalRef<FormLoaderModalComponent>) {
  }
}



--- 
<div class="modal-header">
  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{ title }}</h5>
  <button
    type="button"
    class="btn-close"
    aria-label="Close"
    (click)="modalRef.close()"
  ></button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="modalRef.close()">
    Close
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>





so very basic but get the error.
Wondering what I might be doing wrong and how to fix the issue.
Thanks

It looks like the library you are using is attempting to access the Teams parent window which is not allowed. It is advised that the developer should reach out to the MDBootstrap library's owners for support here. Any libraries that Teams Apps depend on should support rendering in a cross-origin iframe.

Please refer this doc for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tab-requirements
